# Should I separate this question into two?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[My question about usury during Shemittah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46088/5) got derailed by my use of an example of lending physical objects. I am inclined to remove the example (perhaps replace it with a better one), and then ask a separate question about lending physical objects and their status as loans more generally.  One person, however, has posted an answer attempting to address both issues.  Should I separate the question into two?

Comment: I'm not sure what the right thing to do is, but should you decide to split your question, leave the answerer a link to the new question in a comment under his answer, so he has a fair shot at answering the new question.